# Are App Registration API Permission changes delayed?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the function `GetMemberGroups` to check if a user is in an AD group. This works just fine in dev/localhost. As soon as I push it to QA though, I start getting the following error/exception.

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
>   Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

This [msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0) states that I would need `User.Read` or greater permissions to use this function as a delegated user.

So I went into my Azure AD App Registrations and both Dev and QA had this permission. So then I decided to remove all permissions from Dev. After doing this, Dev still works just fine and QA still throws the above error message.

Are permission changes delayed? Am I wrong about the required permissions? What craziness is happening here.

After making changes to app registration permissions I get the following warning:

> Permissions have changed. Users and/or admins will have to consent
>   even if they have already done so previously.

I never get any prompt to accept or deny, even after signing out and signing back in.

[image: Azure AD App Registration API Permissions for Dev]

Comment: I think you may have run into a known issue where documentation isn't correct about the least permission required to call this API.. I don't think `User.Read` delegated permission works for this API.. take a look at the issue posted here.. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3938 and also this SO thread that has a very detailed discussion on the same.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269300/how-do-i-obtain-the-azure-ad-groups-of-the-currently-logged-on-user-without-need/55271475#55271475

Comment: Okay, so I have granted Dev `Directory.Read.All` previously, but I removed it. So why is it still working then?

Comment: That part doesn't sound right.. if you deleted the permissions and did consent again for permissions that requrie Admin consent then they should be removed.. I see `Directory.Read.All` permission both delegated as well as application one needs Admin consent.. so did you perform the consent after removing it?

Comment: A consent never popped up again. How do I get that to happen?

Comment: If you're looking to do consent for the same Azure AD Tenant where you have registered your application, then use the "Grant permissions" button from Azure portal.. if it's a different tenant then you can use URL for Admin consent. Here is a screenshot for Grant consent from Azure portal.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIO11.png

Comment: Okay so apparently my problems stems from not being an Azure Admin. I can add permissions and regardless if it says "Requires admin consent" or not, the grant admin consent button needs to be clicked for changes to be saved properly.

Comment: @Shelby115 Remember that permissions you're choosing in the app registration page are the permissions your app *wants*. They aren't the permissions your app has been granted. Using the "Grant admin consent" button you can attempt to grant the permissions in that tenant, but as you've discovered, only Azure AD global administrators are authorized to grant some permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**App Registration Permissions**

These permissions weren't up-to-date. Apparently Dev still had `Directory.Read.All` permissions, which is the required permissions as Rohit pointed out, despite it not appearing on the list. Once the grant admin button was clicked it stopped working in dev.

I then removed all permissions and only added `Directory.Read.All` to both applications and once the admin grant button was clicked both applications started working correctly.

Thanks to *Rohit Saigal* for the information about the incorrect/bugged documentation.